# How to use Iterators and generators to perform the following operations?

Tags: javascript, json, object, iterator, generator

I want to get the ​data.json​ file, parse into an object, and make it an iterable. (Don't change the object data type into an array)
Make it an iterable using

1. Iterators 2. Generators
   When that object is passed inside a FOR OF loop, I should get the output of each item as the following pattern.
   Post Id: 1 Title: Some title
   Post Id: 2 Title: Some other title
   And so on …
   This is the link for the json file[https://raw.githubusercontent.com/attainu/curriculum-master-fullstack/master/coding-challenges/deep-dive/iterators-data.json?token=AOGF265VMPYWFKXO6RNGXPS67WAMM][1]

```js
console.log("connected");
function fetchJSONFile(path, callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                if (callback) callback(data);
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', path);
    httpRequest.send(); 
}
fetchJSONFile(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/attainu/curriculum-master-fullstack/master/coding-challenges/deep-dive/iterators-data.json?token=AOGF265VMPYWFKXO6RNGXPS67WAMM`, function(data)
{   
data[Symbol.iterator] = function() 
{
    var c=0;
  return {
      // I Don't know how to access the key of the object inside the object , Can you help me please?? 
    next() {
        c++;
      if (c <= data.length) {
        return { done: false, value: "value" };
      } else {
        return { done: true };
      }
    }
  }};
for (let val of data) {
  console.log(val); 
}
});
```

Comment: The HTTP request is asynchronous. Do you expect to get an iterator *immediately*? Because that is not really how it works. You can only get such an iterator asynchronously.

Comment: can you please elaborate?? I don't understand this at all..thanks in advance..Where can i read more about it?

Comment: @trincot...please help

Comment: I fear that the challenge you try to solve is asking you to produce an iterator on something that is not available now, but in the future (the response to the HTTP request). You cannot iterate something that is not there yet, so do you have more precise information on what is expected?

Comment: Sir @trincot ..Is this part attainable somehow ( When the object is passed inside a FOR OF loop, I should get the output of each item as the following pattern. Post Id: 1 Title: Some title Post Id: 2 Some other title And so on )??Thank You

Comment: I understood that part, since it is in your question, but it doesn't answer my question. Anyway, I have posted an answer. A clarification would be needed.

Comment: @trincot I feel like the XHR is actually a red hering in this code. The actual question is about how to iterate the JSON data using iterators/generators.

Comment: I feel the same about that. But it would be good if the OP could clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this with fetch. You can make changes.
Did little digging. came up with this. You will have to define your own `iterator`. Is this what you wanted ?

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const arr = [];
let status;
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/attainu/curriculum-master-fullstack/master/coding-challenges/deep-dive/iterators-data.json?token=AOGF265VMPYWFKXO6RNGXPS67WAMM') // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
  .then((res) => {
    status = res.status;
    return res.json()
  })
  .then((jsonData) => {
    jsonData[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
      var self = this;
      var values = Object.keys(this);
      var i = 0;
      return {
        next: function () {
          return {
            value: self[values[i++]],
            done: i > values.length
          }
        }
      }
    }
   //you we can iterate over object
    for (var p of jsonData) {
      const obj = {
        "PostID": p.id,
        "Title": p.title
      }
      arr.push(obj)
    }
    console.log(arr)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle error for example
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: I wanted a solution that ustilises symbol[iterator] I know that for of loop uses this iterator but this is not how i wanted it..Thanks anyways....

Comment: @ShivamYadav Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

So you are asked to create a generator and iterator.

It is not clear what is expected: if you create an iterator on the response, then this is only possible when the response has already been received, not at the time you initiate the HTTP request. So that iterator can only exist in the future, at the time the response comes back.

There are at least two distinct ways to do this:

## 1. Create an iterator immediately, but an `async` one

This way you can create it immediately, but the resulting iterator will yield promises, not the actual response values. With `for await ... of` you can get the values from that iterator in an asynchronous manner.

Here is how that looks:

```js
async function * generator(path) {
    const obj = await fetch(path).then(resp => resp.json());
    for (const postId in obj) yield obj[postId];
}

// The main program has to be asynchronous:
(async (path) => {
    // Consume the async iterator that you get from the async generator
    console.log("wait for it...");
    for await (let { id, title } of generator(path)) {
        console.log("postId: ", id, "title: ", title); 
    }
})("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/attainu/curriculum-master-fullstack/master/coding-challenges/deep-dive/iterators-data.json?token=AOGF265VMPYWFKXO6RNGXPS67WAMM");
```

## 2. Create an iterator only after you have received the response

Here you create a normal iterator, and only at the time you receive the response:

```js
function * generator(obj) {
    for (const postId in obj) yield obj[postId];
}

// The main program has to be asynchronous:
(async (path) => {
    console.log("wait for it...");
    // Perform the request
    const obj = await fetch(path).then(resp => resp.json());
    // Consume the iterator that you get from the generator
    for (let { id, title } of generator(obj)) {
        console.log("postId: ", id, "title: ", title); 
    }
})("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/attainu/curriculum-master-fullstack/master/coding-challenges/deep-dive/iterators-data.json?token=AOGF265VMPYWFKXO6RNGXPS67WAMM");
```

Comment: @ShivamYadav Which of the two implementations were you actually looking for? The second, right?

Comment: @trincot..Sorry for the trouble sir but can you explain me this part as well ..How can i create an iterator on the response once it is recieved..this is something beyond my level of understanding : (

Comment: This is what happens in the second snippet in my answer. Notice how there is an await for the JSON response. Only when that promise resolves, the code execution picks up after that to call `generate` for it to return the iterator on the response object.

Comment: Actually, I see that maybe you are not interested in the top level keys of the response object, but in the `id` properties... I updated my answer for that.

Comment: @trincot  thank you once again sir...I really appreciate all your help : ) kudos to you

Comment: @Bergi ,yes i wanted the second one